# WPF Applications crashing on Startup

Tags: wpf, crash

We have some newly setup Client PCs(Win7 64Bit, .net Framework 4.0).

On this machines most of the .net Applications keep crashing on Startup.

Some Applications that keep crashing:

Management Studio 2012

Visual Studio 2012 Installation

All of our developed WPF Software

I tried remote debugging our Application, and i don't get across the InitializeComponents Call in my Main Window.

What can be the cause of that problem?

Comment: You should provide more information about errors

Comment: I had no more infos, no logs have been written. THe Applications just stopped working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the cause has been an old graphiccard driver...